# all possible inputs in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++

given a binary search tree print all possible inputs that will form the same binary search tree.

one simple example will be

```
         2
      1      3
```

we need to print

```
   2 1 3
   2 3 1 


                10
          5            13
       3     6       11    15


  10 5 13 3 6 11 15
  10 13 5 3 6 11 15
  ...
```

i tried solving this by reading the tree breadth wise and shuffling it. But, there could be possible input like

10 5 3 6 13 11 15

Do i need to use DFS here ?? am writing it in C++

Comment: DFS - http://www.dfs.co.uk/ - Good for a sit down - but where is the code

Comment: Seems you need to show all permutations for a value set. It's well known task.

Comment: Any other approach to print all permutations of the tree ??? please help

Comment: yes Netch. But, the permutation should form the same binary search tree. For example. 123 is a valid permutation for the input 2(root) 1 (left) and 3(right). However, 123 will change the tree structure. It will put 1 as root and 2 and 3 as childs. 

we need to print all inputs that form that same binary tree.